Phenylpiracetam And Avocado Oil Reaction Questions
Could anyone tell me what, if any possible, chemical reaction would take between organic avocado oil and phenylpiracetam?
It's a long story, I got the package open and broken, was worried about contamination, so I just went with experimentation on it.

Unless you're the person who edited my question, because you were offended for me calling you out on the exact behavior you demonstrated when you edited it, because you have control issues..
Could the person who down-voted this tell me why? So I can avoid it in the future? I don't understand. Is this not the place for non-chemists to ask questions about chemistry?
This place has become reddit with real expertise, it would seem.

Phenylpiracetem is a di-amide with one primary amide group and one tertiary amide (picture from Wikipedia)
.
Avocado oil is a mixture of unsaturated fatty acids  mainly oleic (18:1) and palmitoleic (16:1) acids further information here.
I can see no possible reactions between them at room temperature in the absence of other reagents/conditions.

I thought it is mostly mixture of triglycerides of these fatty acids, with some being free.

I saw the wiki. Well I've ended up with two different substances. One that is in the oil, and one that separated and is gel-like and does not dissolve in water. It's much different than the original powder and something definitely is now in the oil. I don't know enough about chemistry, but the lab reports say it was 99.87, and there's much less than the 5 grams I started with in the oil that remains as a gel-like white substance that won't dissolve in water so something in in the oil and if it's indeed one molecule, it's either fat soluble or not.

Not to mention the loss in weight in the what which remains, and its now inability to dissolve in water. Seems like something happened, given these changes, differences in weight, and characteristics. It was originally a bit under 5 grams of solid white, water-soluble power.

Though, just to clarify, I'm not telling you that you're wrong and a chemical reaction occurred. As I've said, I have no idea. I just don't understand what happened given what I mentioned above.
Edit: My confusion may be that I've finding two different answers to the question of whether or not Phenylpiracetem is water or fat soluble and it could just be partially dissolved which would make a lot more sense. But multiple websites said it was water soluble so I decided to test it. Could you confirm which of these is true?

Sorry for the more comments. Won't let me edit after five minutes. Just wanted to ask, and while I doubt, I would like to know from someone who doesn't have to guess, would 65 celsius be enough to cause any type of reaction? It's far below its melting point (around 149–152°C), so again, I doubt. But I figured it wouldn't hurt to ask.
Anyway, thank you very much for taking the time to answer. It's hard finding information, especially when you find contradicting information. <3 Much love sire.

Phenylpiracetem is fairly water soluble ~18.5mg/ml with gentle warming and ultrasound. It is readily soluble in ethanol and other polar solvents.  I would guess that it is not very soluble in avocado oil. What you are seeing are physical changes not chemical changes - there is no reaction

Thank you very much. I appreciate it. I marked it correct, I'd upvote it if I could. I've never used the chemistry stack exchange. I've found multiple sources with contradicting information. Would you mind giving me your source on that, or is that just because you understand the molecule itself? Also fun fact, the question I asked, got edited for saying I didn't want to expand on the situation too much because of the word-count police, and they deleted that part. :) Stack was a good concept, until they allowed people to control other people's speech based on upvotes and 'trophies'.

I have no citation for this. It is based on 40+ years of experience as a synthetic chemist.
